# Showing 1 cannot be an eigenvalue after rotating an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have a compact self-adjoint positive integral operator $Q:L^2(0, \infty) \to L^2(0, \infty)$ with operator norm $\| Q\| =1$. By the assumptions, we know $1$ is an eigenvalue of $Q$. Let $y\ne 0$ and consider applying a rotation after $Q$: $$
T_y[f](t) = e^{iyt}Q[f](t). $$

It is not hard to see $\|T_y\|=1$. Is it true that $1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $T_y$?

I think the answer is false in finite dimensional spaces, because we can pick for example rotation by a full circle.

Attempt: I could only deal with $|y|$ small. Since $T_y$ is an analytic perturbation of the operator $Q$, by Kato-Rellich Theorem, there is an analytic function $y\to \lambda(y)$ with $\lambda(0)=1$ (eigenvalue is analytic). By uniqueness of analytic continuation, the set $\{ y\mid \lambda(y)=1 \}$ must not accumulate. It follows that for small nonzero $y$, $\lambda(y)\ne 1$.

If you are intersted, my operator is $$
Q[f](t) = \int_0^\infty f(s) e^{-(t^2+s^2) - \beta(t+s)} I_0(2\sqrt{ts}) ds $$ with $\beta$ suitably chosen so that $\|Q\|=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $T_yf=f.$ Thus $(Qf)(t)=e^{-iyt}f(t).$ Then
$$0\le \langle Qf,f\rangle =\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-iyt}|f(t)|^2\,dt$$
For every positive operator we have
$$\|Qf\|^2\le \|Q\|\,\langle Qf,f\rangle$$
Therefore
$$\int\limits_0^\infty |f(t)|^2\,dt \le \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-iyt}|f(t)|^2\,dt$$ i.e.
$$\int\limits_0^\infty [\cos yt-1]\,f(t)|^2\,dt\ge 0$$
Thus $[\cos yt-1]f(t)=0,\ a.e.$ hence $f=0.$

Comment: Is there a typo in the inequality after "therefore"? I am not sure to follow. The left hand side is real whereas the right hand side is complex. Maybe I am just confused with something.

Comment: @KBS The right hand side is $\langle Qf, f \rangle$, which is real because $Q$ is positive.

Comment: But if it is real, it must be zero because the imaginary part would also need to be zero as well. The implication that $f=0$ is already there. No?

Comment: @KBS The imaginary part is zero, but it does not imply $f=0,.$ The real part is crucial as $\cos yt -1\le 0.$